# Value of margin padding and width properties

Tags: javascript, html, css

Consider the following `html` code snippet:

```
<div id="parent" class="parent">
    <form id="child" class="child"> 
        <input id="textForDim" type="text" /> 
        <input type="submit" value="submit"/>
    </form>
    <div id="divchild" class="childd"><input  type="text" /><br/>
        <div class="cchild"></div>
</div>
```

and corresponding `css` styles

```
.parent{
    position: absolute;
    text-align: center;
    width: 350px;
    height: 450px;
    background-color: #f7f7f7;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 2px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 2px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    box-shadow: 0px 2px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
}
.childd{
    width:200px;
    height:180px;
    background: grey;
}
.cchild{
    background:aqua;
    width:20px;
    height:10px;    
}
```

[**JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/bundos/T9PvK/10/). How i can do that after `submit` button click we have `margin-left,margin-right,width,padding-left,padding-right` in the `textForDim` input as the follow:
`margin-left: _Margin-Left_Value_px, margin-right: _Margin-Right_Value_px,` etcetera...
Is it possible to apply JS for this needs or it's a bad practice?

Where `_Margin-Right_Value_px` is the value of `margin-right` property of `divchild` div element.

Comment: what is `textForDim` and what is `_Margin-Left_Value_px`?

Comment: @E L I'm updated my post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<script>
function doThis()
{
    var k = document.getElementById('textForDim');
    k.style.marginLeft = _Margin_Left_Value_px + "px";
    k.style.marginRight = _Margin_Right_Value_px + "px";
}
</script>

<div id="parent" class="parent">
    <form id="child" class="child"> 
        <input  type="text" id="textForDim" onclick="doThis()"/> 
        <input type="submit" value="submit"/>
    </form>
    <div id="divchild" class="childd"><input  type="text" /><br/>
    <div class="cchild"></div>
</div>
```